# Bootstrap-Table : Resize the column using header

Tags: bootstrap-table

I like to how to resize the column of the table using header for the following example which uses bootstrap-table.

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/resizable.html

Comment: There is a link on that site to view source: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/extensions/resizable.html

Comment: But it does not cover what I expected.

Comment: This is an issue with bootstrap-table's resizeable plugin (was just reading through the source). The colResize is being initialized on the table element, but not on the `.fixed-table-header` element.

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit why it doesnt answer your issue

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of bootstrap-table and resizable plugin seems to reference this:

https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/resizable

A simple fiddle proves that the `headerOnly` toggles this behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/dabros/egqLsfv6/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        resizable: true,
        headerOnly: true,
        data: data
    });
});
```

Next time please try to include a fiddle yourself, even if your unsure how to make it fully functional, as it makes answering questions like this much much easier - you even often solve it yourself before you finish the fiddle.